# Is it possible to use Elastic Enterprise Search through NEST client in C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elastic-appsearch, moss2007enterprisesearch

I want to use Elastic Enterprise Search in C#, is it possible to do it with the NEST client?

Enterprise Search (also known as App Search) offers powerful functionalities for search engines on the web platform. I am trying to use it with NEST Client; however I am not able to post data in Enterprise Search, I am only able to post the data into an index on Elasticsearch.

Any suggestions, references or resources that could help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is **no official Elastic App Search API client in C#** as per [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/enterprise-search/7.16/programming-language-clients.html).

There may be other unofficial clients available or you can write an HTTP wrapper yourself but as of current, one does not exist.

Comment: Can you suggest some unofficial clients available? 
I am not able to find anything for App Search.

Comment: @DAme I can't find any unfortunately

Comment: I confirm, no client in C# for AppSearch. I am considering to create an open source project.

Comment: I am porting the client Elastic AppSearch in C#, in few weeks I would like publish it on github :)

Comment: @DAme, please I would like to know if you were able to port the Client Elastic AppSearch as you mentioned above and if you are happy to share it

Comment: We are working in an Elastic AppSearch Client, partially implementing the functions. We are thinking to publish as an open source project, however, not yet ready.